# What is a pseudo element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm dissecting this very beautiful example of how CSS can help you create nice glow effects on images.

http://jsfiddle.net/necolas/KbNq7/

This particular line from the example mentions:

> Although this method will only produce the full effect in Firefox 4,
>   other browsers will eventually catch up and apply transitions to
>   **pseudo-elements**.

What is a pseudo-element?

Comment: "What is a pseudo element?" [answers](http://bit.ly/19BalsR)

Comment: Also worth knowing - [What is the difference between a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8069973/465053)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Pseudo-elements** are CSS selectors that manipulate parts of an element in a special way.

They include:

- `:first-line`
- `:before`
- `:after`

### Application

Pseudo elements are applied like so

```
p:first-letter{
    color:black;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

**Note:** the `:` followed by the selector is how pseudo elements are denoted in CSS1 and CSS2.  In CSS3, the double colon is used (`::`) to distinguish them from pseudo-classes.

More details here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelements

### Support

Support is decent for a number of browsers, with older versions of IE notably poor with support.  QuirksMode has a compatibility table (a bit out-of-date but still useful): http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15

### Cool Tricks

Pseudo elements can do some cool things, including

1. show the URLs of links in printed docs
2. fake a `float:center;`

See more here: http://css-tricks.com/9516-pseudo-element-roundup/

### With jQuery

jQuery has a number of unique `selectors` that enhance and expand on the native CSS group:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

**Note:** you can use jQuery to force older browsers to adopt certain rules.  For example, IE6 will ignore `:last-child`.  Using jQuery can force IE6 to apply that style.

### The Spec

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-element-selectors

Comment: Note that the `:hover` selector can also be used with other elements.

Comment: `:first-child` is also a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element - I've edited that out for you. Nice answer by the way :)

Answer (score 2):

Its not an element in the dom. Its something you can select with a selector, notably after a `:`.

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/pseudoelements/