# Direct descendant selector with greater than

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I need to select all the list items in all unordered lists where the count is greater than seven.

This code:

```
$("ul.seven > li:gt(6)").hide()
```

is too greedy and works correctly for the first unordered list on the page but hides all subsequent list items of subsequent unordered lists. What is the correct selector?

Comment: If you prefer "the correct selector" over a block of callback code which consists of selector *fragments*, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:gt()` collates the entire set of `ul.seven > li` and picks everything after the sixth `li` in that combined set, regardless of its parent. It's equivalent to selecting all of those `li` elements and then performing a `.slice()` on the result set:

```
$("ul.seven > li").slice(7).hide();
```

Which does something very different from what you expect.

You want `:nth-child()` instead, which [behaves more like what you expect of a CSS simple selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter/10835694#10835694):

```
$("ul.seven > li:nth-child(n+8)").hide();
```

`:nth-child(n+8)` means "starting from the 8th child based on a 1-index", which is roughly equivalent to `:gt(6)` which means "starting from the 7th match based on a 0-index" (confusing, I know). Compare the [Selectors spec for `:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), the [jQuery API documentation for `:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector) and the [jQuery API documentation for `.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of exactly what was wrong in addition to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("ul.seven").each(function() {
    $(this).find("> li:gt(6)").hide();
});
```

or ( which is essentially the same )

```
$("ul.seven").each(function() {
    $(this).children("li:gt(6)").hide();
});
```