# CSS Selector Tester validity

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I just found the following CSS Selector Tester:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp

Is it valid? There are strange selectors there like:

- p:first
- ul li:eq(0)
- :contains(Duck)

For example, the following doesn't work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Selectors</title>
    <style>
        p:first {
            outline: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p>First paragraph</p>
        <p>Second paragraph</p>
        <p>Third paragraph</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z46rm/1/)**

Comment: Is *what* valid? If you are asking if those are valid examples of CSS selectors, the answer is: yes.

Comment: Then why can't I get them to work in Chrome? Why can't I see them in a reliable source like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)?

Comment: I stand correct, these aren't exactly usable selectors. They are somewhat valid, but in obscure ways. I've included an answer for you that hopefully explains them a bit better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xp6m5/

Comment: I know about the `:first-child`. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page you've linked to is mistaken (cue booing and jeering at W3Schools). The selectors listed there are [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors), many of which are non-standard. They are not valid CSS selectors, even though they use a similar syntax.

Although the `:first` pseudo-class is defined for use with the `@page` rule, it is not defined for use anywhere outside it. A selector like `p:first` is not valid in either a style rule or a `@page` rule, nor is it valid in a `document.querySelectorAll()` call. Page selectors are a special type of selector that is described in [this section of CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-selectors) as well as [this section of the Paged Media module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-selectors). While they are part of the CSS standard, they are not considered part of the [Selectors standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors) or related standards, although, like jQuery selectors, they share a similar syntax.

While `:first` is also [defined in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector), it functions very differently in jQuery than in a `@page` rule. The page you link to is obviously demonstrating jQuery's version. I would hesitate to call `:first` a valid *selector* more so a valid *page selector* or a *jQuery selector* because it's so context-sensitive, plus it obviously can't be used in a CSS stylesheet or `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Like `:first`, `:eq()` and their related selectors are non-standard jQuery selectors. They also function very differently to `:first-child`, `:nth-child()`, etc, so while you may be able to use those selectors to emulate them to some extent in CSS, they're not exactly the same (otherwise jQuery wouldn't have created the non-standard ones). See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter) for an in-depth explanation.

As mentioned, `:contains()` was going to be part of CSS but never made it. It's emulated in jQuery anyway, but keep in mind that it may be expensive in terms of performance and/or not work as you might expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Those are (mostly) valid selectors, albeit somewhat obscure.

```
:first
```

This is a selector for styling the first page of a document when printed. Browser support seems iffy, at best. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first

In your example markup, it appears you want the first item styled, in which case you'd instead use `:first-child` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

```
:eq(0)
```

This is a jQuery CSS selector. In pure CSS, you'd likely use `:nth-child` to do the same. See: http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

```
:contains()
```

This selector was proposed, but never made it into the spec. See: [Why doesn't the selector h3:nth-child(1):contains('a') work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781141/why-doesnt-the-selector-h3nth-child1containsa-work/4781167#4781167)