# Last unknown element in known div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How do you select the last child element in a known div where the child element is an unknown element. i.e: the element can be a paragraph or un-ordered list.

Most occasions the structure will be:

```
<div id="container">
<p>Text</p>
</div>
```

but on other occasions, the structure will be:

```
<div id="container">
<p>Text</p>
<ul>
<li>More Text</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.last()`

```
$('#container').children().last().show();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:last-child` on its own without a type selector, like so:

```
$('#container > :last-child')
```

This is equivalent to specifying the `*` selector in place of a type selector (the `*` is optional and implied in this case, but you can put it in if it makes the code clearer to you):

```
$('#container > *:last-child')
```

This will get you the very last child regardless of what type of element it is. In your first structure, it's the `p`, and in the second structure, it's the `ul` (its `li` child is *not* included).

This is a valid CSS selector as well, so you can also use it in a stylesheet should you desire.

Comment: Standards-based selectors should be preferred.

Comment: @Shomz: I think so too, but I'm not familiar enough with `:first`, `:last` and `:eq()` to be sure, [because they work differently from standard CSS selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter/10835694#10835694). I know for absolute certain that `:last-child` will work with the given markup, however.

Comment: Sure, sure, just saying... gave you +1 right away. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/last/

Use jQuerys last method on all div's children.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:last` Selector

Try This

```
$('#container > :last')
```