# JSOUP Can't find item, :eq seems to be off by 1

Tags: html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, jsoup

I am trying to use a very specific jsoup selector to pull some data from a page however it seems like the first instance of a :eq is off by one.  For example for the page: [Example Page](http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/)

I am using the following selector to select the title of the article:

```
html>body>article:eq(0)>div:eq(0)>header>h1
```

a snippet of the html from the page looks like:

[image: Snippet]

So the above selector doesn't work but interestingly this one does, where the first occuence of eq has its index bumped by one.

```
html>body>article:eq(1)>div:eq(0)>header>h1
```

The code I am using is:

```
Document doc = null;

try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect( "http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/" )
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4; Nexus 4 Build/KRT16H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36")
            .get();
    Element ele = doc.select(toast).first();
    if(ele != null){
        System.out.println(ele.text());
    }

} catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have also confirmed the same thing is happening on:[Try Jsoup Online](http://try.jsoup.org/)

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that is so bizarre. I was able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

[jsoup's selector documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) is very sparse, even when it comes to non-standard selectors such as `:lt()`, `:gt()` and `:eq()`. The examples aren't very helpful either:

> `:lt(n)`  elements whose sibling index is less than *n*
> `td:lt(3)` finds the first 2 cells of each row
>
> `:gt(n)`  elements whose sibling index is greater than *n*
> `td:gt(1)` finds cells after skipping the first two
>
> `:eq(n)`  elements whose sibling index is equal to *n*

Based on what little it *does* say, however, my guess is that jsoup's version of `:lt()`, `:gt()` and `:eq()` are nothing more than zero-indexed versions of `:nth-child()`, which means `article:eq(0)` is functionally equivalent to `article:nth-child(1)`, and `article:eq(1)` to `article:nth-child(2)`.

This is very much unlike their jQuery counterparts, [which behave completely differently from `:nth-child()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter/10835694#10835694). If anything, the jsoup ones seem utterly superfluous, not to mention unnecessarily confusing for those familiar with jQuery selectors.

But then again, none of these selectors were ever part of the standard to begin with, so while jsoup's documentation could have been much, much clearer, it's not *wrong* of it to implement them differently from jQuery (although I still have to question why they bothered implementing them in the first place). This is why I avoid non-standard selectors like the plague unless there are absolutely no other alternatives.

Since these selectors don't do anything `:nth-child()` can't already do in jsoup, you are better off using the standard selectors:

```
html>body>article:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(1)>header>h1
```

Comment: eq(0) does not work. and these selectors are part of css3, no?

Comment: @momo: No, they're not, and have never been.

Comment: "This is why I avoid non-standard selectors like the plague unless there are absolutely no other alternatives." - they are part of the standard. And nth-child selectors don't work in jsoup, which led me here.

Comment: @momo: Your original comment was clearly talking about :eq() and not :nth-child(). Again, :eq() has never been part of any standard (unless you consider jQuery a "standard"); :nth-child() is (I even state as much in the last paragraph) and if *that* doesn't work, which again is *not* what your original comment was saying, then something else is wrong. Please don't say one thing and mean another.