# CSS selector incorrectly works with comma

Tags: html, css-selectors, jsoup

Could you please clarify if CSS selector that I use incorrectly works with comma or is it me not fully understanding how it should work ?

I'm trying to parse table of this page
http://www.citefactor.org/journal-impact-factor-list-2014_0-A.html

Following CSS selector returns tree elements instead of two

```
div.panel-body.news > table > tbody > tr:eq(2),tr:eq(1)
```

You can test it using https://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: The link that you provided do not have your example.

Comment: The `:eq` selectors are not CSS selectors as far as I know. And, both those selector strings give me only 2 elements in the test page.

Comment: @Harry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955825/jsoup-cant-find-item-eq-seems-to-be-off-by-1

Comment: @Error404 You can use "Fetch" button on jsoup site to load HTML of first link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does the below selector fetch 3 elements instead of 2?**

`div.panel-body.news > table > tbody > tr:eq(2),tr:eq(1)`

The above selector string indicates the processing program to do two things (first corresponds to the part before comma and second point corresponds to the one after comma):

- Find the `div` element with `class='panel-body news'`. Among its ***direct children*** (the `>` means select only direct children and not descendants), find all `table` elements and then within that list find all `tbody` elements which are direct children of the table. Now, under the collection of `tbody` elements, pick the third `tr` (the `:eq(2)` part as the index is 0 based).
- Select all second `tr` elements (that is, select second row of each table).

In your code, there are two `table` elements. First table is the one with the index on the top and next is the one with the actual data. So, the following are the elements that are fetched:

- Third row of the data `table` because this is is a direct child of `div.panel-body.news`. The other table with the index on top is ***not a direct child*** of `div.panel-body.news` because it is put under a `center` tag. Moreover it has only two rows anyway and so the first part matches one element.
- Second row of both the index table and data table because the direct child relation is not applied after the comma in the selector string. So, it matches the row with N-Z in index table and the 2nd row in the data table.

**So, why does the following selector select only 2 elements then?**

`div.panel-body.news > table > tbody > tr:eq(1),tr:eq(2)`

The above selector would select only two elements because :

- Only the data table is a direct child of the `div.panel-body.news` and so the selector string before comma would match only the second data row
- There are three rows only in the data table (the index table has only 2 rows) and so the part after the comma matches only the third data row.

**So, can you explain the below also?**

`div.panel-body.news > table > tbody > tr:eq(1),tr:eq(3)`

The above selector would select only two elements because :

- Only the data table is a direct child of the `div.panel-body.news` and so the selector string before comma would match only the second data row
- There are four rows only in the data table (the index table has only 2 rows) and so the part after the comma matches only the fourth data row.

**Ok, so what is the correct selector if I want to fetch the second and third data rows?**

You should write the selector as follows:

```
div.panel-body.news > table > tbody > tr:eq(2),
div.panel-body.news > table > tbody > tr:eq(1)
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, Harry!