# Feasability of element[attribute]:nth-of-type(n) selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

This question has to do with the way selectors work and is not a problem I am having. I was working with some HTML similar to this:

```
<div class="example">
    <textarea>...</textarea>
    <textarea for="1">foo</textarea>
    <textarea for="2">bar</textarea>
    <textarea for="3">hello</textarea>
    <textarea for="4">world</textarea>
</div>
```

I was trying to use `$('.example').children('textarea[for]:nth-of-type(1)')` to select the first textarea with the `for` attribute. I kept getting undefined. I reread the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) and noticed the line saying

> Selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent in relation to siblings with the same element name.

And it makes sense that `textarea[for]:nth-of-type(1)` would be returning undefined because the first textarea doesn't have the `for` attribute.

My question then is, would it be possible in the future for an `element[attribute]:nth-of-type(n)` selector to return the nth element with the specified attribute? Would this require a whole new selector because of the way jQuery/CSS work?

Comment: *"would it be possible in the future for an `element[attribute]:nth-of-type(n)` selector to return the nth element with the specified attribute"* - No, because as you already pointed out, that's not how `:nth-of-type()` works. It's based on the element's tag **type**. You may already know this, but for the record you can just use the `:eq()` selector or `.eq()` method to get an element by its index *based on the set* of matching elements. In your case, `$('.example').children('textarea[for]:eq(0)')` - an index of `0` is used since `eq` is zero-based and `:nth-of-type` isn't,

Comment: @JoshCrozier I did in fact use the `:eq()` selector. So I guess a whole new selector would be required to do a nth-of-type-esque selection in conjunction with the attribute selector then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question then is, would it be possible in the future for an `element[attribute]:nth-of-type(n)` selector to return the nth element with the specified attribute?

Not really, because the "type" in `:nth-of-type()` has a very specific meaning, and because it's not very intuitive for a simple selector to match an element based on any other criteria than the element's own characteristics as reflected in the DOM or similar.

> Would this require a whole new selector because of the way jQuery/CSS work?

Yes, and this is why Selectors 4 introduced `:nth-match()`, which has since become an extension to the existing `:nth-child()`, that considers only a subset of elements according to a selector argument. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-another-selector). In your case it would be

```
$('.example').children(':nth-child(1 of textarea[for])')
```

This is still not implemented anywhere; hopefully that will change in the new year.

Since this is jQuery, you can use `:eq(0)`, but unless you will only have exactly one such `.example` and one such textarea, you may need to iterate the `.example` elements using `.each()` (thanks to how [unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter/10835694#10835694) these non-standard selectors are).

Comment: This is great, thanks! The whole `:nth-child(1 of textarea[for])` is kind of ugly in my opinion, but I'd have to deal with it I guess. Hopefully browser support will come around soon.

Comment: @mcon: I agree. Its only advantage is in being far more obvious in what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

nth-of-type use index from an actual DOM not from filtered list, so `nth-of-type(1)` will find you first textarea `<textarea>...</textarea>` but you filtered it by `[for]` ... `nth-of-type(2)` is `<textarea for="1">foo</textarea>`

`nth-of-type(3)` is `<textarea for="2">bar</textarea>` etc...

So answer is No, you can not use `nth-of-type` for this.

For getting first textarea child with "for" you can just use document.querySelector

```
var first = document.querySelector('.example > textarea[for]');
var first = document.querySelectorAll('.example > textarea[for]')[0];
//or jQuery
var first = $('.example > textarea[for]:eq(0)');
```

BTW in `nth-of-type` index starts from 1 not from 0...

Answer (score 0):

**From my point of view, It is not a limitation, It is implemented well enough for patters.But not for your case (selecting single node), also we don't need it at all.**

In your case you don't need to use the nth-type-of(n) since you are selecting single node not a set with some pattern like (odd , even , 2n+1)

For your case you can try the below one

```
 $('.example textarea[for]').first()
```

If you relay have a scenario to select set of node with nth-of-type(n). Yes it will work w/o any issues.

```
$('.example textarea[for]:nth-of-type(2n)')  This selector is working well enough.
```

see the demo > Run code Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.example textarea[for]:nth-of-type(2n)').css('background-color', 'red');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <textarea>...</textarea>
  <textarea for="1">foo</textarea>
  <textarea for="2">bar</textarea>
  <textarea for="3">hello</textarea>
  <textarea for="4">world</textarea>
</div>
```