# can ":next-of-type" be synthesized?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Came across a situation using large grids of mixed types of elements, where it would be nice to have `:next-of-type` as a pseudo-class. My definition of that would be the next sibling that is of the same type as the element selected by the selector to which `:next-of-type` is appended. (I suppose it would also be nice to have `:next-child`, `:next-of-class`, etc. And prev-child, prev-of-type, prev-of-class, etc.)

Couldn't find such a thing in the CSS documentation, so I guess it doesn't exist. I spent some time trying to synthesized it out of what does exist, and failed.

Not sure if this is solvable, maybe only by the W3 CSS working groups...

As an example, assume you have a large grid of elements. For simplicity, I'll just use two in the example, but my actual case has a dozen or more different types of elements. I'll number the elements content in the order they would exist in the HTML, but due to grid placement algorithms (not demonstrated here) the items might not actually appear in a different order than in the HTML. Nonetheless, the sequence of items in the HTML is of interest to the selection plan. I'll use `<a->` and `<b->` for the (custom) elements.

```
<div style="display: grid;">
     <a->1</a->
     <a->2</a->
     <b- class="special">3</b->
     <a->4</a->
     <a- class="ordinary">5</a->
     <a- class="surprise">6</a->
     <b->7</b->
     <b->8</b->
     <a->9</a->
</div>
```

So it would be nice to have a way to specify `.special:next-of-type` and select item 7, `.ordinary:next-of-type` would select item 6, and `.surprise:next-of-type` would select item 9.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it's more of an idea discussion, but fundamentally these pseudo-classes would match *different* elements than the one represented by whatever you "attach" them to, and so wouldn't be compatible with CSS's definition of "pseudo-class" or indeed "simple selector". For example, .special:next-of-type doesn't match *that* .special, it matches *another* element altogether. A human reading that might intuitively understand what it does, but it still doesn't jive with the selector syntax, and I don't think the CSSWG will support it for that reason.

Comment: (Well, the "can it be synthesized" part is on-topic, but the answer is "no" and the remaining discussion seems to detract pretty heavily from that anyway...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a spec recommendation more than a programming issue (what BoltClock said).

Comment: @BoltClock, Not sure I've intuited the CSS definition of "pseudo-class" such that :next-of-type would be incompatible with it. Do you have a spec reference? A selector is a way of selecting things, and indeed, people give directions by saying "turn left at the 2nd street after the traffic signal", so I think it is an understandable concept, as well as implementable, but maybe it does break some philosophy, as you suggest (but I'd like to see the text that makes you think so).

Comment: Yes, the "can it be synthesized" is why I asked the question here: just because I failed to synthesize it, doesn't mean someone else couldn't.  + and ~ implement similar concepts, but not exactly this one. The problem I'm facing could be solved by insuring that all the elements of like type are siblings (but that would disturb the placement algorithm, and I couldn't figure out a solution for that either), or by running some javascript that alters/augments the class tags (and I did solve the issue that way, but would have preferred a CSS solution).

Comment: Hmm. One extra piece of information I do know about the sequence of elements in the maximum number of elements that might appear between two elements of the same type. So maybe a collection of strings of + and :not operations could be combined to achieve the effect.... sure would be ugly, though.

Comment: @Victoria: [Selectors L4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#syntax) describes simple selectors and compound selectors as conditions matching against a single element. Something like :next-of-type is not a condition for an element, but establishing a relationship between that element and some other element. In Selectors, relationships between two or more different elements are represented with combinators. I don't think this could be made to work with a combinator, though. I'm not sure if this could be done with a functional pseudo-class and if so, what that functional pseudo would look like.

Comment: (Functional pseudos are just the CSSWG's hacky workaround for this limitation, as demonstrated with :has() and L4 :nth-child().)

Comment: So a combinitor could be desgned, but not likely as a single-character as all the currently-existing combinators that I'm aware of. :has(), as you point out, is a condition on some child selector and :nth-child( of S) adds a condition or a parent, but still focuses on the described selector rather than moving to another. So combinators would be the focus of designing a "real solution for the standard"... as well as the building block for a synthesized solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is possible, but in addition to knowing a complete list of the types of elements in the grid, and a maximum span of elements between elements of the same type, it would be really handy to have a macro-processor to generate the synthesized solution.

The snippet below deals only with two types of elements, and a maximum of 5 elements between elements of the same type, but could obviously be laboriously extended in either dimension.

```css
      .container {
        display: grid;
        font-size: 30px;
        grid-template-areas:
          ". . ."
          ". . ."
          ". . .";
      }
      .special ~next-of-type { color: red; }
      a-.special + a- { color: red; }
      a-.special + :not( a- ) + a- { color: red; }
      a-.special + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: red; }
      a-.special + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: red; }
      a-.special + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: red; }
      a-.special + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: red; }
      b-.special + b- { color: red; }
      b-.special + :not( b- ) + b- { color: red; }
      b-.special + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: red; }
      b-.special + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: red; }
      b-.special + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: red; }
      b-.special + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: red; }

      .ordinary ~next-of-type { color: blue; }
      a-.ordinary + a- { color: blue; }
      a-.ordinary + :not( a- ) + a- { color: blue; }
      a-.ordinary + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: blue; }
      a-.ordinary + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: blue; }
      a-.ordinary + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: blue; }
      a-.ordinary + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: blue; }
      b-.ordinary + b- { color: blue; }
      b-.ordinary + :not( b- ) + b- { color: blue; }
      b-.ordinary + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: blue; }
      b-.ordinary + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: blue; }
      b-.ordinary + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: blue; }
      b-.ordinary + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: blue; }

      .surprise ~next-of-type { color: orange; }
      a-.surprise + a- { color: orange; }
      a-.surprise + :not( a- ) + a- { color: orange; }
      a-.surprise + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: orange; }
      a-.surprise + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: orange; }
      a-.surprise + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: orange; }
      a-.surprise + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + :not( a- ) + a- { color: orange; }
      b-.surprise + b- { color: orange; }
      b-.surprise + :not( b- ) + b- { color: orange; }
      b-.surprise + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: orange; }
      b-.surprise + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: orange; }
      b-.surprise + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: orange; }
      b-.surprise + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + :not( b- ) + b- { color: orange; }
```

```html
    <h1>next-of-type synthesized</h1>
    <div class=container>
     <a->1</a->
     <a->2</a->
     <b- class="special">3</b->
     <a->4</a->
     <a- class="ordinary">5</a->
     <a- class="surprise">6</a->
     <b->7</b->
     <b->8</b->
     <a->9</a->
    </div>
```

Thanks to BoltClock for saying it wasn't possible, and other helpful comments that led me to this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround isn't practical for my use case, which has 45 different types of elements, and particular pairs of element types might have up to 120 elements of other types between them. So it would take 5400 selector combinations, most of which would be extremely lengthy, to use this technique as a workaround.

Comment: Breaking down the feature, I guess the combinator feature would be "first that matches"... the current combinators are + "first if matches", and ~ "all that match". With "first that matches", the above solution could be reduced to one line per type of element of interest...  for the last example in the set that would be  a-.ordinary (new-combinator) a- {color: blue;]  b-.ordinary (new-combinator) b- {color: blue;}

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comments:

Fundamentally, pseudo-classes that match "next" and "previous" elements would match different elements than the one represented by whichever compound selector you "attach" them to, and so wouldn't be compatible with CSS's definition of "pseudo-class" or indeed "simple selector"/"compound selector".

[Selectors L4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#syntax) describes simple selectors and compound selectors as conditions matching simultaneously against a single element. By this definition, a selector like `.special:next-of-type` is only going to work if the next element of that type also matches `.special`. It'd then match recursively, resulting in all of `.special ~ .special` except the first of each element type in each parent element. Critically, it would not work at all in your case, as item 7 does not match `.special`.

A human reading that selector might intuitively understand what it does, but it still doesn't jive with the selector syntax, because for it to work you'd need to define `:next-of-type` as a special pseudo-class that ignores or matches separately from the rest of the compound selector, contrary to how it's been defined in the spec. This means added complexity for selector matching algorithms. A similar complexity can be seen in [jQuery's `:eq()` family of selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983297/difference-between-css-selector-and-jquery-filter/10835694#10835694) — there's probably a good reason those selectors haven't been standardized.

Additionally, something like `:next-of-type` is not a condition for an element, but establishing a relationship between that element and some other element. In Selectors, relationships between two or more different elements are represented with combinators. A "next sibling of type" combinator would make light work of this task without fundamentally changing how selector matching works (e.g. `.special ~~ *`), but one does not exist in any Selectors spec, and I can't see use cases such as this one being common enough for the CSSWG to justify designing, testing and implementing it. And without such a combinator, you'd need to know the element type in advance in order to determine the next sibling of that type, and that can't be accomplished using selectors available today, not even including L4 `:nth-child(An+B of S)`.

So the answer to

> can ":next-of-type" be synthesized?

is no, not with selectors available today, and a solution that would work with the existing selector syntax is to introduce a combinator with this exact functionality.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reference, which I read in-line with your text, and as I did, realized that to fit those definitions, what would be needed is a combinator. And finishing reading your answer, you arrived at the same conclusion. So your definitional concern expressed earlier in comments was just syntactical, not functional... had I invented combinator syntax instead pseudo-element syntax, your comments would have been different, and had you mentioned combinator as the alternative they would have been more clear. Thanks for elucidating.