# Why can't I override existing pseudo-elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-specificity

I have two CSS rules following each other:

```
.some td:first-child:before {
    content:url('path/to/image.png')" " ;
}
.some .other:before {
    content:url('path/to/image2.png')" " ;
}
```

Here's the HTML snippet:

```
<table class="some">
<tr>
    <td class="other">Text goes here</td>
    <td>Some more text.</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

They're both supposed to be applied to the same table cell. The one without the class is meant as a fallback. But for some reason, it's always choosing the first rule over the second. I know the 2nd one works, since it will be used if i disable the first one in Firebug.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Will `.some td.other:before` not work?

Comment: The first has [more specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) than the other.

Comment: @JohnH: problem with that is, that "other" will be different, and the fallback rule is supposed to take over, if there's no explicit rule for a specific class.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: why? the 2nd one has two class selectors, the first just one. Shouldn't it use that one instead if it matches?

Comment: The first appears to be 31 (three second-level selectors plus an element selector), the second 30 (three second-level selectors, no element selector). Look at how to [calculate your selector specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: @JaredFarrish: You're right. Adding a `td` before `.other` does the trick. Need to read up on pseudo-element specificity... Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, to put this straight, after [some](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) [reading](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), this is the specificity:

- Id: **100**
- classes: **10**
- pseudo-*classes*: **10**
- pseudo-*elements*: **1**
- elements: **1**

So that makes the first selector have a specificity of 22, and the 2nd of just 21. Apparently `first-child` seems to be a pseudo-class and not a pseudo-element.

Finally, adding a `td` before `.other` does the trick, since then document order takes precedence.

Comment: That's right, yes, a pseudo class is just like a class (in this case, a class name that would be assigned to all first elements) while a pseudo element is a new element in the DOM, in this case one that would be inserted before the element in question. Does that make sense?

Comment: One could argue all one likes, but no, a class is not an element. Just like in your example, `some` is not an element, only the table with `class="some"` is. Even if you change the class name so it sounds like an element, `class="theThirdTable"`, it's still not an element!

Comment: See [What is the difference between a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

The first rule is more specific than the second one, so in a case when both the selectors are valid, the more specific one overrides other.

Read [this](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) article to know how can we overcome such complications of having conflicting styles. To brief them, Here is how specificity are calculated.

> ```
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> |    Type            |   Specific Value   |  Example                          |
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> |  Inline Style      |   1000             | style="color: #f00;"              |
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> |  Id                |   100              | #text { color: #f00; }            |
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> |  Classes           |   10               | .text { color: #f00; }            |
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> |  Pseudo Classes    |   10               | a:hover { color: #f00; }          |
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> |  Pseudo Elements   |   10               | a:first-child { color: #f00; }    |
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> |  Elements (tag)    |   1                | a { color: #f00; }                |
> +--------------------+--------------------+-----------------------------------+
> ```

Basically, Class Selectors are more specific than tag selectors. 
Lets calculate your specificity

- For first rule: 31
- For second rule: 30

SO the first rule wins.

You can increase the specificity of the second rule like

```
.some tr td.other:before {
    content:url('path/to/image2.png') ;
}
```

Its calculate to 33, to override the style first rule.

Comment: Thing is, it's always using the first one, not the 2nd.

Comment: @DanMan, Oops, i calculated the specificity and you are right, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's to do with the specificity. Try adding `!important` to the second rule and see if that works.

Comment: `!important` is a last resort means, to be used if everything else fails.

Comment: Agree on the caveat. But in this case, it's a decent suggestion to quickly see if it can be overriden, answering whether or not it has to do with specificity without having to pin down exactly why.