# Overriding a pseudo element

Tags: css

So I have a list that starts with a FontAwesome icon and then some text, which I'm trying to style individually (size and color). For example I want the Skype icon to be #00abeb in color

This is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="contact-entries">
<li class="icon-mobile-phone">Mobile</li>
<li class="icon-phone">Landline</li>
<li class="icon-skype contact-skype"><a href="skype:misc?chat">misc</a></li>
<li class="icon-envelope-alt"><a href="mailto:contact@misc.org" title="Email">contact@misc.org</a></li>
<li class="icon-map-marker">Address</li>
</ul>
```

The main CSS styling is this:

```
.contact-entries > li { position:relative; }
.contact-entries > li:before { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; color: white; font-size:20px; }
```

And I created this myself to change the size and color of the Skype icon, but it won't work:

```
.contact-skype { 
    color: #00abeb !important;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to change font color or background color?

Comment: Use `#background-color: #00abeb !important;` instead of `color: #00abeb !important;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.contact-entries .icon-skype.contact-skype { 
    color: #00abeb;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Should do it if no  !important elsewhere or heavier selector on li .

Comment: Which part of the original code should I substitute with this one?

Comment: wich rule are you actually trying to override ?i do not see any in the bit you gave.

Comment: The icons are white color because of .contact-entries > li:before I'm trying to override it and make the Skype icon #00abeb. Here is the actual website: [www.cyper.org](http://cyper.org) - the Contact Us section.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to change the background color. You should do..

```
background-color: #00abeb !important;
```

*instead of:*

```
color: #00abeb !important;
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to change the color of the text and the icons individually. The icons are just a vector font, which can be fully styles via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the color of the link you can just set the color or your 'a' elements to 'inherit' to have the link inherit the color from the li. Here's a fiddle for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/hVurc/

```
.contact-skype {
    color: #00abeb;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
a{
    color:inherit;
}
```

Or you could use a child combinator selector like this:

```
.contact-skype > a{
    color: #00abeb;
}
```

If you want it to have that background-color, just set the background-color to #00abeb. Here's a fiddle for that as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/RwTHP/1/

```
.contact-skype {
    background-color: #00abeb;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Edit:
Here's a link that might be helpful.

- [Why can't I override existing pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055921/why-cant-i-override-existing-pseudo-elements)

Comment: Here is the actual website: [www.cyper.org](http://cyper.org) - the Contact Us section. I want to make the Skype icon #00abeb in color, the text all white and each icon to have different font size, because some are bigger than others by design.