# Difference between pseudo class, pseudo selector, and pseudo element in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css)

What do the following mean in CSS?

1. Pseudo class
2. Pseudo selectors
3. Pseudo element

What is the usefulness of each?

Comment: @SLaks: I imagine the reaction from the OP will be "that question doesn't say anything about pseudo-selectors!"

Comment: @SVS w3schools is one of the worst sites to learn coding . Check http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Subhra: Then have you checked http://www.w3.org yet? I answered your question because despite what SVS and gar_onn said, you won't find satisfactory results using Google (especially for "pseudo-selectors"), but at the same time I downvoted your question because it's poorly-written and shows no sign of research... unlike your previous question.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for answering first of all . Well I knew that possible there could be a duplicate of the same but then I also saw the term "Pseudo Selectors " and that confused me even more. Anything in http://www.w3.org/ is so much elaborate that I find experts answering the relevant parts more useful. I do not mnd getting some down votes but what matters is that I learnt something from the post.

Comment: Too harsh on the down-votes...

Comment: I found the question to be useful so +1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes) are used to select elements according to information that you can't otherwise express using attributes, IDs or classes (or any other info available through the DOM). For example, `:root`, `:first-child`, `:last-child`, `:lang()` and `:not()`.

[Pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) are mock elements that you can apply styles to selectively as part of other actual elements, but aren't themselves members of the DOM. For example, content fragments such as `::first-line` and `::first-letter`, or generated content such as `::before` and `::after`.

"Pseudo-selectors" is an umbrella term used to cover both kinds of selectors (or really any selector that begins with at least one `:`), but it is itself meaningless, because in Selectors, pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements are two fundamentally different things.

Comment: It's worth noting that pseudo-elements only officially got the double colon (::) syntax starting with CSS3, they still work with a single colon (:) for the sake of backwards compatibility.

Comment: After so many downvotes, I just wanted to say thanks for giving a good answer. I think the question is very valid, and this helped me understand. Thanks!