# What does the '::' selector mean in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I came across a blog-post, where `::` was used in their CSS code.

Here is part of their code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}
```

The code is working fine for the scrollbar, but I could not find where this selector is defined. What does this officially mean

Comment: http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/05/after-v-after-what-is-double-colon-notation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::` signifies a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements), as opposed to a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-classes) `:`. Pre-CSS3 they both used `:` and support is a little scrappy for the `::` syntax still.

**A pseudo-class filters existing elements.**

`a:link` means all `<a>`s that are `:link`.

**A pseudo-element is a new fake element.**
`div::after` create a "fake" element with `<div>` but after its content.

### References

- [What is the difference between a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8069984/1156119)
- [Pseudo-element tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info)

Comment: `div::after` actually is a fake element within `div` but _after_ its content. This is actually noted in the comment to your post you link to. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info.