# Whats the difference between pseudo element markers : and ::?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I've noticed that both `:` and `::` work when marking up pseudo elements in CSS. I'm sure there is some semantic difference between the two, no? I'm not really seeing it.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [CSS3 selector specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) section on [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements):

> This `::` notation is introduced by the current document in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, `:first-line`, `:first-letter`, `:before` and `:after`). This compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements introduced in this specification.

Comment: Background information from the spec: “A [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) always consists of a "colon" (`:`) followed by the name of the pseudo-class and optionally by a value between parentheses.” “A [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) is made of two colons (`::`) followed by the name of the pseudo-element.”