# CSS, select if :first-child has class="selected"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two `<a>` in a `<p>` and I want to assign them different borders when selected.

When the user clicks on a `<a>` a JavaScript sets the class to `"selected"` and the border shall turn to green if it is the first `<a>` but if the second `<a>` is clicked and assigned class="selected" the border shall turn to red.

What I would like to do in CSS is something like:

```
a:first-child.selected {border-color:green}
a.selected {border-color:red}
```

But that does not work.

There are a lot of examples out there which describes how to select the first-child of a specific class but none which describes how to select the first-child of a certain tag IF it has a certain class.

Is this possible to achieve at all?

What I have done now is to set the first `<a>` as `class="yesselected"` and if the second is clicked it will have `class="noselected"`.

But i would really like to know if it is possible to select a tag if it is the first one and it has a certain class

Comment: Have a look at [CSS3 selector :first-of-type with class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447045/css3-selector-first-of-type-with-class-name)

Comment: So, that *should* work. Is the `a` *really* the `:first-child`, or simply the `a:first-of-type()` Can you show your HTML? And the JavaScript that's adding/changing the class-names? Also, [it works in this (simple) demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DDtuZ/).

Comment: I updated my question sice all tags were lost.

Comment: RienNeVaPlus: That answers my question! I was aware of the selector but didn't know that it was possible to also include a class in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally thought your css was slightly off, you needed the pseudo element at the end. That appears to be wrong in the case of pseudo classes. Thanks to @BoltClock's a Unicorn

```
a.selected:first-child {border-color:green}
a.selected {border-color:red}
```

However I have to ask if your css sets the border to appear somewhere else with all of the needed border value declarations?

```
a{border: 1px solid transparent;}
a.selected:first-child {border-color:green}
a.selected {border-color:red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8hPw8/

Comment: It's not a pseudo-element - it's a pseudo-class, so it doesn't matter whether you put it before or after the class selector.

Comment: really? that's interesting and not how I understood the spec.

Comment: Yup. It says [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-child-pseudo) that it's a pseudo-class. A pseudo-class and a pseudo-element while similarly named are not the same thing - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css).

Comment: Or if you were referring to the ordering of selectors - it's not explicitly mentioned anywhere that you can have them in any order, but [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax) you can find a definition for "simple selector".

Comment: @DrCord: You are absoutley correct. From what I have read I simply assumed that a.classname:first-of-child would select the first a-tag with class=selected which would not work if my second a-tag had class=selected. The reason why I need to be so specific is because it is only small a part of a quite large website.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be 
    a.selected:first-child
?

Edit: Boltclock is right, the ordering doesn't matter.

It's to do with the exact behaviour of the [:first-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) selector.

```
a:first-child
```

refers to the ***a*** tag that is the first child of it's parent element and not to the first **a** child of an element.