# Does pseudo first-line need double colon syntax?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've found that using a single colon with the pseudo tag first-line works fine.  Why is a double colon used for this tag and is it really needed?

From WC3 Schools:

```
p::first-line 
{
color:#ff0000;
font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

But this works fine:

```
p:first-line 
{
color:#ff0000;
font-variant:small-caps;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: w3schools is horrendously unreliable, see http://w3fools.com, and contrary to what it tries to make people believe, it is not affiliated with the W3C in any way, or an authority of any kind.

Comment: In this case, w3schools was right.  I haven't had issues with their reliability.

Comment: It wasn’t. It does not even mention the alternative `:first-line` syntax, it incorrectly says that “pseudo-elements are used to add special effects to some selectors”, it refers to “CSS classes” (there is no such thing), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line) states:

> In CSS 2, pseudo-elements were prefixed with a single colon character.
>   As pseudo-classes were also following the same convention, they were
>   indistinguishable. To solve this, CSS 2.1 changed the convention for
>   pseudo-elements. Now a pseudo-element is prefixed with two colon
>   characters, and a pseudo-class is still prefixed with a single colon.
>
> As several browsers already implemented the CSS 2 version in a release
>   version, all browsers supporting the two-colon syntax also support the
>   old one-colon syntax.
>
> If legacy browsers must be supported, :first-line is the only viable
>   choice; if not, ::first-line is preferred.

Further, as the [W3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#pseudo-elements) states:

> This :: notation is introduced by the current document in order to
>   establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.
>   For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also
>   accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced
>   in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, :first-line, :first-letter, :before and
>   :after). This compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements
>   introduced in this specification.

Answer (score 0):

[MDN for ::first-line (:first-line)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-line)

> CSS3 introduced the ::before notation (with two colons) to distinguish pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept :before, introduced in CSS2.

The situation on `::before` and `::after` are pretty much the same.

> CSS3 introduced the ::before notation (with two colons) to distinguish pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept :before, introduced in CSS2.

- [MDN for ::before (:before)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)
- [MDN for ::after (:after)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

You might ask:
**What's the difference between Pseudo-classes and Pseudo-elements?**

- [Answer from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements)
- [Answer from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css)