# How to add a border after heading in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a border image after every header in Wordpress, but the following isn't working

```
h1:after {
content:' ';
border:2px solid rgb(229,164,20);
margin: 25px 0;
display:inline-block;
width: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML. Cause it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9mnujnyy/ If you want the border under the heading, just do a `border-bottom` on the `h1` itself.

Comment: What do you want the border to look like in relation to the heading text? a 45px wide line underneath the heading text, aligned left?

Comment: @Aibrean idk, for some reason it's not showing up in wordpress. Here's the link: http://tudorice.com/.. I would like it to show up under every h1 element. The border is visible on one page, but i coded it using a span tag.

Comment: Have you tried using `::` instead of `:`?

Comment: @Howlin no what's the difference ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20471091/3204827) link should explain the difference.