# Is it possible to increase the padding of an element while not affecting its border?

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar that includes the usual links, and to [improve the user experience I have a bottom border show on hover](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95753/how-can-i-make-it-more-obvious-that-these-are-links):

[image]

I achieve this with the following code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #E9EBEE;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.nav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 6em;
  background-color: #F6F7F9;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav > .links {
  margin-top: -36px;
  border-left: solid 1px #E9EBEE;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.nav > .links > .link {
  float: left;
  position: inherit;
  border-right: solid 1px #E9EBEE;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  width: 8em;
  transition: border-color .2s;
}
.nav > .links > .link:hover {
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #3B5998;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  color: #3B5998;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="links">
      <div class="link">
        Servers
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'd like the border to be on the bottom of `nav`; to do this I added `padding-bottom:11px;` to `.nav > .links > .link`, which resulted in this:

[image]

The result is exactly what I wanted, however notice that the right and left borders of each navigation item has been extended; something that I should've realised would happen when adding the `padding-bottom` attribute to `.nav > .links > .link`.

To fix this I thought that I could use a `border-bottom-height` since there is a `border-bottom-width` but apparently no such thing exists, and I don't want to use an additional element if possible to provide the left & right borders. As seen in the first image, the left and right borders should be approximately the height of the text contained.

Is this possible without an additional 'wrapper' element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pseudo element instead, i.e. `::after` (if to support IE8, use `:after`, works cross browser)

```css
body {
  background-color: #E9EBEE;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.nav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 6em;
  background-color: #F6F7F9;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav > .links {
  margin-top: -36px;
  border-left: solid 1px #E9EBEE;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.nav > .links > .link {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border-right: solid 1px #E9EBEE;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  width: 8em;
  transition: border-color .2s;
}
.nav > .links > .link:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 11px);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;  
  background: #3B5998;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="links">
      <div class="link">
        Servers
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: good answer. technically, pseudo-elements should have two colons (`::after`) to distinguish them from pseudo-classes like `:hover`. ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css))

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Very correct, though it also says _For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, :first-line, :first-letter, :before and :after)._

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow This is me which still has IE8 users, hence need to use the single colon version, ...will make a comment about it in my answer

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. In most cases, the simplest and cleanest option would be to create a pseudo-element (as suggested by LGSon), but sometimes this isn't possible. For example, you may already have used both pseudo-elements for other effects, or you may not be able to position it properly (notice that the pseudo-element method requires you to set the `.link` element's position property to `relative` -- this may not always be possible for your layout).

Below is an alternative technique, using box-shadow. It has its own drawbacks, most notably that it only works when working with a solid-color background.

The idea is simple: draw two box-shadows (since they can stack!) on the hovered element. The bottom one is two pixels taller than the top one. The bottom one is blue, the top one is the same color as the nav bar.

```css
body {
  background-color: #E9EBEE;
  color: #666666;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.nav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 6em;
  background-color: #F6F7F9;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav > .links {
  margin-top: -36px;
  border-left: solid 1px #E9EBEE;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.nav > .links > .link {
  float: left;
  position: inherit;
  border-right: solid 1px #E9EBEE;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  width: 8em;
  transition: border-color .2s;
}
.nav > .links > .link:hover {
  color: #3B5998;
  box-shadow:
    0 11px 0 #F6F7F9,
    0 13px 0 #3B5998;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="links">
      <div class="link">
        Servers
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm accepting LGSon's answer as I was able to use pseudo elements, however `box-shadow` seems intriguing and is a good alternative.