# Are : hover, :checked , :active etc. Called css events?

Tags: html, css, events

I've using css `:hover` , `:checked` etc. a long time.
But still don't know, what css `:hover` , `:checked` etc. are called.
What is it's name?
Are they called css events?
If they are, is there any css events for `<radio> (`I mean, custom style after choosing an html radio) ?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css

Comment: @Vanna And yet the answers are there with a little searching. This is not that difficult to Google. Even w3schools gets this one right.

Comment: I didn't know, what to search on Google. So I asked in stack overflow.

Comment: @user8575948 Googling "css :hover :checked" would tell you pretty quickly. You've been using them for years; how/where did you learn what they did?

Comment: @TylerH not using them for a year. Just started using them some months ago

Comment: @Vanna It is a duplicate if OP is asking about something already asked about/answered, even if OP doesn't know the right name. That's the point of the duplicate system -> to point people to the existing helpful content

Comment: @TylerH I'm agreeing your action. But will choosing my question as duplicate, decrease my reputation?

Comment: I don't want to decreas my rep. So if you say so, I'll delete the question.

Comment: And also, please don't down vote my question

Comment: I don't even have much reps for upvoting others questions and answers.

Answer (score 5):

They are called 'pseudo-classes'.  You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

Comment: Which pseudo-class is usable for custom styling when a radio is choosed?

Comment: You could probably find that information by entering the same question into google...

Comment: If I don't know what the thing (pseudo-class) is called, then it is not a good way to search anything I heard about css, in search engines.

Comment: Like is :hover called class selector?,. Is :hover css events?    Is :hover called ****? etc.

Comment: I apologize if it sounds like I'm being harsh, but this is kind of a "teach a man to fish" kind of situation.  From you comments, it looks like you didn't look at the link I included in my answer.

The next step isn't that complicated.  Now that you know they are called pseudo classes, you can search for pseudo classes for radio buttons.

Comment: oh! You are right.

Comment: Now, I'll search Google.

Comment: And, at last, bye.