# Select nested elements via css3

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can i hide the strong line via css...?

Is the .col-md-12 of the third row... is not the row, is the col

```
.bannerHeader .row:nth-child(3) .col-md-12 {display:none}
```

does not run....

```css
.bannerHeader .row::nth-child(3) .col-md-12 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="bannerHeader"><br>
  <div class="row"><br>
    <div class="col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="gwt-Label gwt-Label-BannerFormatLink">Text</div><br>
    </div><br>
  </div><br>
  <div class="row"><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-Label Inline">Text</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div><br>
    </div><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-Label Inline">Text</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div><br>
    </div><br>
  </div><br>
  
  <div class="row"> <br>
<!-- this col should be selected -->
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-HTML Inline">Text</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div> <br>
    </div><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-HTML Inline">Text</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div><br>
    </div><br>
  </div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: instead ::nth-child(3) - :nth-child(3)

Comment: excuse me, is the col inside the 3rd row....,

Comment: `::` is for pseudo-elements, but `nth-child()` is a pseudo selector. `:` is the correct prefix for pseudo-selectors.

Comment: What are all those `<br>` elements for? They prevent your approach from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few flaws in your selector

```
.bannerHeader .row::nth-child(3) .col-md-12 { }
```

In the first version of your question, you use `::nth-child` with a double colon.

`:` are pseudo-**classes**
`::` are pseudo-**elements**

The difference is well explained here:
[What is the difference between a pseudo-class and a pseudo-element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css)

The second problem is that you use a class selector combined with a pseudo class selector. (Fixed the `:` here)

```
.row:nth-child(3)
```

Which isn't false.
I however believe that you use this to select the **third `.row` element**. Well, there isn't a `nth-of-class` selector. What this selector does, it selects the **third child that also has the `.row` class**.

Which doesn't give you what you want.
If you look at the HTML in my snippet, I've commented the children of `.bannerHeader`. The `<br />` also count as children. So the **third `.row`** is actually the **sixth child**.

So instead I advice you to filter on the `div`, rather than the class. To do so, use the pseudo selector `nth-of-type`:

```
.bannerHeader div:nth-of-type(3)
```

Additionally you could add the `.row` selector as well. Which in my opinion is obsolete.

```
.bannerHeader div.row:nth-of-type(3)
```

Then after your edit, you say you want to select the first `.col-md-12`. Same as above, you can't use `nth-` on classes, so instead again use `nth-of-type`. In this case the `:first-of-type` or the equivalent `nth-of-type(1)`.

You'll also need to use the direct child `>` selector:

```
.bannerHeader div:nth-of-type(3) > div:first-of-type
/* or */
.bannerHeader div.row:nth-of-type(3) > div.col-md-12:first-of-type
```

All together:

```css
.bannerHeader div:nth-of-type(3) > div:first-of-type {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bannerHeader">
  <!-- child 1 -->
  <br> 
  <!-- child 2 -->
  <div class="row"><br>
    <div class="col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="gwt-Label gwt-Label-BannerFormatLink">Text</div><br>
    </div><br>
  </div>
  <!-- child 3 -->
  <br>
  <!-- child 4 -->
  <div class="row"><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-Label Inline">Text</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div><br>
    </div><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-Label Inline">Text</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div><br>
    </div><br>
  </div>
  <!-- child 5 -->
  <br>
  <!-- child 6 -->
  <!-- this row should be selected -->
  <div class="row"> <br>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text to be selected</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-HTML Inline">Text to be selected</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div> <br>
    </div><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12"><br>
      <div class="row"><br>
        <div class="col-md-4">Text</div><br>
        <div class="col-md-8"><br>
          <div class="gwt-HTML Inline">Text</div><br>
        </div><br>
      </div><br>
    </div><br>
  </div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: `::` is for pseudo-elements, but `nth-child()` is a pseudo selector. `:` is the correct prefix for pseudo-selectors. This should be pointed out additionally. Instead, you copied the error in your introductory code quotation.

Comment: excuse me, is the first col inside the 3rd row

Comment: Also, it is important that OP understands that neither `:nth-child()` nor `:nth-of-type()` care for the css class restriction in the selector.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @connexo, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much