# Bootstrap icon remove ::before

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, pseudo-element

I am adding bootstrap icons dynamically and I want these to appear in new lines. However the result is that the icons and text are appearing in the same line. See image

[image]

this is the code that is generated:

```html
<div class="row ml-1" id="refine">
  <br>
  <i class='bi bi-trash'>
    ::before
  </i> 
    "A1 - North Somerset core strategy"
  <br>
  <br>
  <i class='bi bi-trash'>
    ::before
  </i> 
    "Ashton Vale"
  <br>
  <br>
  <i class='bi bi-trash'>
    ::before
  </i> 
    "NPPF Sept 23"
  <br>
 </div>
```

How can I get the icon/text to appear on separate lines? is it something to do with the autogenerated `::before`? If so, how do i supress that?

Comment: First of all, you should not just be pouring content into a `row`. You need at least one `col` element in there next. (The `row` class applies `display: flex`, and that is why you do not see the `br` elements have any effect right now.)

Comment: You could make a list where the `<li>`get `display: block;`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069973/what-is-the-difference-between-a-pseudo-class-and-a-pseudo-element-in-css for info on `::before`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the class `row` to `col` of the `#refine` div, like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col ml-1" id="refine">
  <br>
  <i class='bi bi-trash'></i> 
    "A1 - North Somerset core strategy"
  <br>
  <br>
  <i class='bi bi-trash'></i> 
    "Ashton Vale"
  <br>
  <br>
  <i class='bi bi-trash'></i> 
    "NPPF Sept 23"
  <br>
 </div>
```

And the ::before is not part of the DOM, it's just a marking of the pseudo element in the browser.